# Ignoring XML comments when parsing a REST feed in WP7

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I'm feeding my app a REST feed from a private web server that is automatically inserting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

in to the feed. The app works fine when reading the exact same XML file locally without the XML comment. I've tried using XmlReader along with it's setting IgnoreComments to no avail, as well as messing around with XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration. How would I go about ignoring this line?

My current code is

```
var restFeed = from xe in xml.Elements("product")
                                select new SearchResult
                                {
                                    Name = xe.Attribute("name").Value,
                                    ID = xe.Attribute("id").Value                                        
                                };
            lb1.DataContext = restFeed;
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's an XML header, not a comment.  XML comments look like this: `<!-- my comment here -->`

Comment: Does that make is easier to ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to parse the data coming back with an `XDocument`, then get the document Elements.  You've not show what `xml` is, exactly, so I'm assuming it's an `XElement`.

Comment: 'xml' is an XDocument that is parsing the REST feed.

'XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(feed);'

Comment: Show us the XML you're parsing.

Comment: An example of the XML I'm using is

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product name="Generic Name" id="ID Number">
</product>`

Comment: Yes, the WP7 Emulator gives the following error `XmlException was unhandled.

Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`